# Recursion limit in Python when indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, stack-overflow

I was fooling around with the [recursion limit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) in Python, which may be dynamically altered using `sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)`. The code below demonstrates that the integer `limit` exactly corresponds to the maximum depth allowed for recursive function calls.

For recursive *indexing* using `[]`, the same recursion limit seems to apply, but apparently with a factor of 3, meaning that I can index three times deeper than I can call:
[image]

The above plot is generated by the code below.

```
import itertools, sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

limits = np.arange(10, 500, 100)

# Find max depth of recursive calls
maxdepth = []
for limit in limits:
    sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)
    try:
        n = [0]
        def fun(n=n):
            n[0] += 1
            fun()
        fun()
    except RecursionError:
        maxdepth.append(n[0])
a, b = np.polyfit(limits, maxdepth, 1)
plt.plot(limits, maxdepth, '*')
plt.plot(limits, a*limits + b, '-', label='call')
plt.text(np.mean(limits), a*np.mean(limits) + b, f'slope = {a:.2f}')

# Find max depth of getitem
maxdepth = []
n = 0
l = []; l.append(l)
for limit in limits:
    sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)
    for n in itertools.count(n):
        try:
            eval('l' + '[-1]'*n)
        except RecursionError:
            break
    maxdepth.append(n)
a, b = np.polyfit(limits, maxdepth, 1)
plt.plot(limits, maxdepth, '*')
plt.plot(limits, a*limits + b, '-', label='getitem')
plt.text(np.mean(limits), a*np.mean(limits) + b, f'slope = {a:.2f}')

plt.xlabel('Recursion limit')
plt.ylabel('Max depth')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

To test the recursive indexing I append a list `l` to itself and construct a long literal `[-1][-1][-1]...` which I then evaluate on `l` dynamically.

Question: Explain this factor of 3.

Comment: In my case I get a factor around 0.58 for call and 1.75 for getitem, which makes even less sense... 1.75/0.58 is still about 3 though.

Comment: That was for small depth. Gets actually closer to 1 and 3 as I increase the limit. I still stay below 1 for call though when it should intuitively be exactly 1 for all cases. Interested to know what hidden mechanism is at work here...

Comment: Strange. I found 1.00 and 3.00 on both Python 3.7 and 3.5, 64bit Linux Mint. I guess this could be platform dependent?

Comment: @Julien: Some of the limit is expended on the test code and provides a constant offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s **no recursion** in `l[-1][-1]…`—it compiles to “push `l`; replace top of stack with its last element; replace…”.  Your `RecursionError` is from **compiling** the long string.

There is very literally a [factor of 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8f59ee01be3d83d5513a9a3f654a237d77d80d9a/Python/symtable.c#L248) used to approximate the stack usage of the byte-compiler *vs.* the interpreter proper.  (Python 2 has no such limit and just crashes on such expressions.)